# Howto Install PHPLinq library on Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Ive been battling this all day.  Is there a way to install PHPLinq so it works with the Zend library autoloader?

Alternatively, if I just have to use include,  is there a way that I can ensure the pathing for the other includes in the PHPLinq library.

Obviously Im new to PHP and just getting this library to get recognized in Zend has been a day killer.  Never Thought id pine for the days of working in .Net  :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an link to the PHPLinq library you're using?

Comment: http://phplinq.codeplex.com/ , http://plinq.codeplex.com/ and http://linqforphp.codeplex.com/ are the three I'm aware of... I'm guessing OP is using the first

Comment: You can write an autoloader class for the PHPLinq library that you can push onto the `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` stack. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8820536/131824

Answer (score 1):

AutoLoading in Zend can be used with any library that supports the naming convention of Zend. That is, put classes in a folder and then all classes underneath it follow the:

```
FOLDER_SUBFOLDER_FILENAME
```

pattern. So you need to have for example:

> MyLib > ClassName.php

And the class must be called

```
MyLib_ClassName
```

If these requirement are ok, then just doing:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'));

// Ensure /libraries is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/libraries'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

//Include the Zend Autloader
include('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');

//Create the autoloader and register the Activis_ namespace
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('YourFirstLevelFolder_');
```

Then when you have registered your namespace and made sure your classes work with the naming convention, using NEW should load ANYTHING you configured.

Good luck