# How to autoload a singleton class (private constructor) in zend controller?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I have a singleton class in my models directory and I have to use its function in Controller class. Doing it by require_once('file path'); and calling function as ClassName::FunctionName() works fine, but I need to use Zend Autoloader instead of including class through require_once. I came across number of solutions here on stackoverflow which used bootstrap.php in terms of adding following code there and it seems like doing the same as require_once('file path'); did in controller

```
  protected function _initAutoload()
    {   
       Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    }
```

Going this way I get Fatal error: Class 'ClassName' not found in {path}\controllers\SampleController.php on {line no.}
I am sure I am missing something but cant figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like user1145086 has rightly said, if you follow the naming convention of Zend, you class should be auto-loaded.

If you have a class, say *AutoloadedClass*, and you want it auto-loaded, you can do the following:

1. Create a folder in your */library* folder and name it *'My'*.
2. Write the following code in your Bootstrap's initAutoload class method:

   ```
   Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace(array('My_'));
   ```
3. Place the file containing the *'AutoloadedClass'* in the *'My'* folder you just created and rename the file to AutoloadedClass.php so the file is eventually located thus: */library/My/AutoloadedClass.php*
4. Lastly, rename the class itself to My_AutoloadedClass as Zend's naming convention requires. You can henceforth get a reference to your class using that class name My_AutoloadedClass from anywhere in your application.

Comment: Or subclass the problematic class and put a `require_once` at the top: `require_once 'SomeClassWithProblematicFilename.php'; class My_AutloadedClass extends TheProblematicClass {} `

Comment: in this way i have to add some Prefix (My_ in this case) to my class. Is there any way to autoload a class with name ,for instance, SampleClass (having no prefix)

Comment: You have to put your classes (with the proper naming convention) in a particular registered namespace (just like 'My') for it to be loaded automatically. Otherwise, you would have to either write your own autoloader class or use require/include_once.

Comment: got it, i managed to change the Class name as per prefix. thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

if you name your class according to zend conventions, the class should autoload without problem.
If your class is located at */application/models/myClass.php* and is named :

```
class Application_Model_MyClass {

    public function myMethod(){
    }
}
```

it should autoload just fine, I don't think the fact that is a singleton would affect autoloading.

If you need to use your own class names you can add a new namespace to the autoloader the works in the */library* directory, add this line to your *application.ini* :

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "MyNamespace_"
```

then add the */MyNamespace* directory to the */library* directory and name your files accordingly:

```
class MyNamespace_MyClass {
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Class to be loaded is not a model class. I cant add any prefix before class name.

Comment: @sidra can you tell us why? Maybe a bit more detail of your actual problem should be added to your question.

Comment: ya sure. I have a FileUploader class, having addFile function. This file is residing there in models directory and I cant change its name but can change its path i.e. can place it in library folder. Now i have to use FileUploader::addFile() by autoloading this class there in controller. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If class names and locations in your library do not follow [Zend naming conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html), then you can write an autoloader for that library and push this autoloader onto the `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` stack.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820536/131824 for an example.

Comment: in this way i have to add some Prefix (My_Loader_Autoloader_ in this case) to my class. Is there any way to autoload a class with name ,for instance, SampleClass (having no prefix)

Comment: @SidraSultana: No, I think you are misunderstanding. No prefix necessary. Your custom autoloader - like the one in the PHPExcel example linked in the above answer - is pushed it onto the Zend autoloader stack. It implements a method `public function autoload($class)` that checks the desired `$class` against the names of the classes that need some special include/require handling. If no match, return false (quickly, so the other autoloaders in the stack get their chance). Otherwise, perform your specialized include/require to load the class and return true.

Comment: ya you are right. I mis-interpret My_Loader_Autoloader_PHPExcel as a class to be required in the controller whereas PHPExcel is the required class. Thanks alot David Weinraub