# integrating phpthumb in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, phpthumb

Is there a easy way to integrate phpthumb in zend framework ? Please help me with sample code if possible, thanks

Comment: See this answer, it may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8820536/212940

Answer (score 1):

application/Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('PhpThumb_');
    return $autoloader;
}
```

application/configs/application.ini

```
[production]
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

put files in

```
library
--PhpThumb
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on this [answer by David Weinraub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820536/212940) as it may not be clear to you how to translate that answer to your situation. I suppose you wouldn't have posted this question otherwise.

I am assuming you are using the [Zend Framework recommended directory structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html).

Under your `library` directory create a `phpthumb` directory and copy all the files from the zip archive into it.

Add the following line to application.ini

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "phpthumb_"
```

Create your autoloader, mine is in `App/Loader/Autoloader/PHPThumb.php` and looks like this:-

```
class App_Loader_Autoloader_PHPThumb implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface
{
    public function autoload($class)
    {
        if ('phpthumb' != $class){
            return false;
        }
        require_once 'phpthumb/phpthumb.class.php';
        return $class;
    }
}
```

Initialise your autoloader in your bootstrap:-

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap 
{
    protected function _initAutoloading() {
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->pushAutoloader(new App_Loader_Autoloader_PHPThumb());
    }
}
```

Once that is done you can use php thumb thus:-

```
$phpthumb = new phpthumb();
var_dump($phpthumb);
```

I have tested this only so far as to instantiate an instance of phpthumb, I haven't tested it's functionality. Also, you may be able to delete many of the files in the phpthumb directory as it looks to me as if many of them are demo files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory name custom inside your 'library' folder . Inside this 'Custom' directory put PHPThumb library as it is . Basically we are exploiting the fact library directory is part of include_path . So now wheresoever you want to use it just simply do

```
require_once'Custom/PHPThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php'
```