# Change Zend autoload path for certain prefixes

Tags: zend-framework, path, namespaces, autoload

I am going to write down a simple example to show what I need, because after 3 hours of research I didn't manage to find a similar thing to this.

I have all my classes starting with `Project_`. Eg. `Project_BaseController` is the base controller class.

The `BaseController.php` is located at `/www/Core/` (that is one of the paths in `set_include_path`), but the autoloader searches it at `/www/Core/Project/`.

I would like to set the path to `/www/Core/` for every class starting with `Project_` (after that it should find the files after naming, like: `Project_User => /www/Core/User.php`)

Maybe `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` is what I need?

I doubt it because it is for resource's not kind of global config.

Answer (score 1):

The method you name your classes violates PSR-0 principal, which ZF has adopted. It would be easier for you to follow PSR-0. In this case the only thing you left to do is to relocate your Project_ classes to Project directory.

Answer (score 0):

The approach used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159281/integrating-phpthumb-in-zend-framework?lq=1) may help. A custom auto loader seems to be the way to go here. –

Add the following line to application.ini

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "App_"
```

Adjust this to match were you keep your library files, I keep mine in `library/App`.

Create your autoloader  in App/Loader/Autoloader/Project.php like this:-

```
class App_Loader_Autoloader_Project implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface
{
    public function autoload($class)
    {
        $project = explode('_', $class);
        if ($project[0] != 'Project'){
            return false;
        }
        $project[0] = '/www/core';
        require_once implode('/', $project) . '.php'
        return $class;
    }
}
```

Initialise your autoloader in your bootstrap:-

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap 
{
    protected function _initAutoloading() {
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->pushAutoloader(new App_Loader_Autoloader_Project());
    }
}
```

Obviously, I don't have an environment to match yours, so I am unable to test this. However, I have adapted it from my own use of autoloaders, so it should work without too much tweaking.

I originally came across this technique thanks to an [answer posted by David Weinraub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820536/212940) and have found it extremely useful since.

Having said all that, [akond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12636825/212940) is good advice and would be the preferred option; work with the framework, not against it. I provide this answer in case that is not an option for you.