# How to load a class in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I got a PHP library ([PHP Markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/)) in my `library` fold in an standard Zend Framework application. What is the best way to load the file and all it's classes to use in my models and controllers.

Structure:

```
library/phpMarkdown/markdown.php
```

Note:
PHP Markdown has a really ugly structure: It's only real "API" is a simple function, not a class. So the elegant was do not work for **this exact case**, but regarding the question the genearl solution the correctly named files/class is also "the right answer.

*Edit*
So much good input here, really not sure which answer I should accept! Thanks to you all!

Comment: FYI I used the Textile (not markdown) library and its structure/class name was not directly compatible with Zend Framework autoloading system. I had to put the `Textile.php` file in a `library/Textile/` folder and rename the class inside from `Textile` to `Textile_Textile`. Yup, a bit weird, but it works. Maybe you'll have to do something like that.

Comment: For an example of creating a custom autoloader for classes that are not PSR-0 compliant, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8820536/131824

Comment: Thats also really helpful, thanks. Wow so much good input here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it simple and just add that one file, you could put something like this in your `Bootstrap.php`:

```
 protected function _initLoad(){
        Zend_Loader::loadFile('markdown.php', '/../library');

    }
```

I just copied markdown.php into the application library and put this little function in the bootstrap. You could also use [Zend_Loader::loadClass();](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.load.html#zend.loader.load.class) if you want.

Comment: This works just fine. But this means I have global access to all functions/classes in the `markdown.php` and that is loaded every time the application is called?

Comment: so if you don't need it application wide, you can put the same code in the init() method of any controller or just use it in an action

Answer (score 2):

[The autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)

Just instantiate the class and the autoloader should find it. If it doesn't you need to add the namespace and path.

Comment: I already had a look at it, but I can't figure it out! Could you give my an example?

Comment: Sure, can you provide a little more information about your file-structure?

Comment: Done. But I found the solution @RockyFord just fine. But if you have anything to add, e.g. for this case you should use this, generally that, for example what is more efficient etc. would be great!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class in the following tree (for exemple) : library/My/Tool.php

You will need to add this to your application.ini :

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"
```

And then in your code you just call :

```
$tool = new My_Tool();
```

**Edit :**

in the file Tool.php you must follow the Zend Naming Conventions and have something like this :

```
<?php

class My_Tool {

}
```

For more informations see this : [Zend Naming conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)

Comment: This only works if the class in `library/My/Tool.php` is called `Tool` right? I cant't get it to work some how, but the filename is not the same as the class name ...

Comment: The class inside the Tool.php must be named My_Tool :